# create and publish two API's on two different endpoints using single API instance in wso2

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Can we create two API's and publish it in two different endpoints as shown below. 
Endpoints example:
 API1 : https://localhost:8244/API1
 API2 : https://localhost:8245/API2

I know we can achieve it by using multiple gateways but it uses more than one API manager instances.

Can anyone suggest is it possible using single API manager instance in wso2?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by this?

Comment: Single API manager will be on single port, it is not possible for an application to start on multiple ports

Answer (score 1):

You can use a reverse proxy (eg. nginx) in front of API Manager to listen on 2 ports and forward the requests to APIM.